# Endless connect to Lync

Tags: connection, lync

We are running a Lync server in our network and some people can login just fine. But others try to connect and nothing happens. The Lync Client tries to connect forever and does not stop with an error message. It just keeps connecting...

What is wrog here?

Comment: You're going to have to provide so much more detail that that to have a hope of solving this. What clients are the users using, are they all on the same network hardware, can different users logon on other machines. i.e is it user based or machine based. More detail = more chance of a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Coworker found the solution:

- Open **certmgr.msc**

  - browse to **own certificates -> certificates**
  - delete Lync certificate
- Open **regedit**

  - browse to **current user -> software -> microsoft -> communicator**
  - change **savepassword** from **1** to **0**
- Reset Passwort for Lync in Lync domain
- Restart Lync

Comment: Are you sure that deleting the cert will help you?

Comment: I am not sure if that step can be ignored. Doing all the above solved the issue for me. I can reproduce ignoring other steps now.

Comment: I had the same problem and tried Juergen's solution. It didn't immediately work, so when Lync was open, I cancelled the sign in and then pressed the link named something like "Delete saved credentials". I then tried to sign in again, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues, it turned out to be my fault, I was a bit too quick deplyng the server and forgot to issue and deploy the second cert

Default Certificate = Check !
OAuthTokenIssuer = None ! = Fail !

In Step 3 "Request, Install or Assign Certificates" in "Install or Update Lync Server System".

When that was done I could migrate from Lync 2010 Server to 2013 without any hickups !